# How to limit the file upload while uploading folder

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am allowing the user to upload the folder as below

```
<input type="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)" webkitdirectory directory multiple/>
```

It Works as expected. But I want to limit the total size to be less than 20 MB. How Can I achieve that

```
  onFileChanged(event): void {
    const allFiles = event.target.files;
    console.log(allFiles);
  }
```

Is there any direct way to do that or I need to loop through each file and calculate the total size and check if its exceeding?

Comment: So you want to block everything if it exceeds or you want to fill as much as possible?

Comment: If you did not do that yet: The server needs to limit it as well, client-side validation is just for user convenience.

Answer (score 1):

Yes from a file input you need to loop through all its `.files` entries:

```js
inp.onchange = e => {
  const total_size = [...inp.files].reduce( (sum, file) => (sum + file.size), 0 );
  console.log( "total size", total_size.toLocaleString( "en-US" ), "b" );
};
```

```html
<input type="file" id="inp" webkitdirectory>
```

Answer (score 0):

`event.target.files` will return [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList). Then you can use `Array.from` and use `reduce` to get the size of each file. This is in javascript and html. Same can be done in angular

```js
function fileUpload(e) {
  const sz = Array.from(e.target.files).reduce((acc, curr) => {
    return acc += curr.size;
  }, 0)
  console.log(sz)
}
```

```html
<input type="file" multiple onchange='fileUpload(event)'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get overall size of the files and prevent uploading:

```
onFileChanged(event): void {
    const overallSize = event.target.files
       .reduce((a, c) => {return (c.size / 1024 / 1024) + a }, 0);
    if (overallSize > 1) // 1 Mb
        alert('File size exceeds 1 MB');
    else {
    }    
}
```